# How to set 'Content-Disposition' and 'Filename' when using FileSystemResource to force a file download file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-3, content-disposition

What is the most appropriate, and standard, way to set the `Content-Disposition=attachment` and `filename=xyz.zip` using Spring 3 `FileSystemResource`?

The action looks like :

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/action/{abcd}/{efgh}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/zip")
@PreAuthorize("@authorizationService.authorizeMethod()")
public FileSystemResource doAction(@PathVariable String abcd, @PathVariable String efgh) {

    File zipFile = service.getFile(abcd, efgh);

    return new FileSystemResource(zipFile);
}
```

Although the file is a zip file so the browser always downloads the file, but I would like to explicitly mention the file as attachment, and also provide a filename that has nothing to do with the files actual name.

There might be workarounds for this problem, but I would like to know the proper Spring and `FileSystemResource` way to achieve this goal.

P.S. The file that is being used here is a temporary file, marked for deletion when the JVM exists.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/action/{abcd}/{efgh}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@PreAuthorize("@authorizationService.authorizeMethod(#id)")
public HttpEntity<byte[]> doAction(@PathVariable ObjectType obj, @PathVariable Date date, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    ZipFileType zipFile = service.getFile(obj1.getId(), date);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + zipFile.getFileName());

    return new HttpEntity<byte[]>(zipFile.getByteArray(), headers);
}
```

Comment: But note that this will break if the filename contains non "token" characters, such as whitespace, non-ASCII, and certain delimiters.

Comment: short answer `response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + YOUR_FILE_NAME);`

Comment: Avoid code-only answers. Provide some explanations about the snippet!

Comment: I like this simple approach. Worked for my project.

Comment: put the file name between double quotes `"`.

Comment: Beware, if the filename is not properly sanitized, this solution can lead to an easy cross-site-scripting attack!

Comment: As mentioned by @PhilippePlantier you should escape the filename - https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ContentDisposition.Builder.html

Answer (score 73):

In addition to the accepted answer, Spring has the class [ContentDisposition](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ContentDisposition.html) specific for this purpose. I believe it deals with the file name sanitization.

```
      ContentDisposition contentDisposition = ContentDisposition.builder("inline")
          .filename("Filename")
          .build();

      HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.setContentDisposition(contentDisposition);
```

Comment: Interestingly until very recently the ContentDisposition class only encoded the filename when the charset was specified as non-US-ASCII: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24220

Comment: If you have to build a `HttpServletResponse` or a `ResponseEntity` using their builder, you can still use the `ContentDisposition` class to generate the header String for you: `response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, contentDisposition.toString());` It will take care of escaping the necessary characters.

Comment: Starting from Spring 5.3, you can use `ContentDisposition.inline()` or `ContentDisposition.attachment()` instead of `ContentDisposition.builder("inline")`.

Answer (score 21):

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/files/{file_name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public FileSystemResource getFile(@PathVariable("file_name") String fileName,HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");      
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=somefile.pdf"); 
        return new FileSystemResource(new File("file full path")); 
    }
```

Comment: what exactly is this method returning? what is myService?

Comment: @user3809938 the constructor for FileSystemResource can take a `File` or `String` for the path

Answer (score 17):

Here is an alternative approach for Spring 4. Note that this example clearly does not use good practices regarding filesystem access, this is just to demonstrate how some properties can be set declaratively.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{resourceIdentifier}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
// @ResponseBody // Needed for @Controller but not for @RestController.
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> download(@PathVariable(name = "resourceIdentifier") final String filename) throws Exception
{
    final String resourceName = filename + ".dat";
    final File iFile = new File("/some/folder", resourceName);
    final long resourceLength = iFile.length();
    final long lastModified = iFile.lastModified();
    final InputStream resource = new FileInputStream(iFile);

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + resourceName)
            .contentLength(resourceLength)
            .lastModified(lastModified)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE) // For Spring 5: APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM
            .body(resource);
}
```

Comment: This should be the preferred way nowadays. Less state is always better.

Comment: Niggle: BodyBuilder.contentType, at least per Spring 5, takes a full MediaType as argument (e.g. APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM), not a String (e.g. APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)

Comment: @JoachimLous Thank you, I've added this as a comment to the code.

Answer (score 1):

Made few changes to both given answers and I ended up with the best of both in my project where I needed to extract an image from the database as a blob and then serve it to the clients :

```
@GetMapping("/images/{imageId:.+}")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource>  serveFile(@PathVariable @Valid String imageId,HttpServletResponse response)
{       
    ImageEntity singleImageInfo=db.storage.StorageService.getImage(imageId);
    if(singleImageInfo==null)
    {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(null);
    }
    Blob image=singleImageInfo.getImage();
    try {           
        String filename= UsersExtra.GenerateSession()+"xxyy"+singleImageInfo.getImage1Ext().trim();

    byte [] array = image.getBytes( 1, ( int ) image.length() );
    File file = File.createTempFile(UsersExtra.GenerateSession()+"xxyy", singleImageInfo.getImage1Ext().trim(), new File("."));
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream( file );
    out.write( array );
    out.close();
    FileSystemResource testing=new FileSystemResource(file);

    String mimeType = "image/"+singleImageInfo.getImage1Ext().trim().toLowerCase().replace(".", "");
      response.setContentType(mimeType);    

        String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
       String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", filename);
       response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);
      // return new FileSystemResource(file); 
       return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body( new FileSystemResource(file));
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Using a ResponseEntity in Kumar's code will help you respond with  the correct Response code.
Note: converting from a blob to a file is quoted from this link: 
[Snippet to create a file from the contents of a blob in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076972/snippet-to-create-a-file-from-the-contents-of-a-blob-in-java)