# Avoid file extension detection in Spring MVC request mapping with floating point number in URI

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I used Spring Boot to implement a REST application. I have one resource that is mapped like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{fromLat}/{fromLon}/{toLat}/{toLon:.+}", method = {RequestMethod.GET},
        produces = {"application/json"})
```

Thus the path contains coordinates and a request looks like this

```
$ curl -I -X GET http://localhost:8085/foobar/53.481297/9.900539/53.491691/9.946046
```

Unfortunatly the last end is interpreted as a file extension which leads to a response header that offers a file download instead of just the plain data.

```
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=f.txt
```

I thought I could handle the situation with a custom WebMvcConfigurerAdapter Bean (and without @EnableWebMvc) annotation like explained [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html).

```
public class CustomWebMvcConfigurerAdapter extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(false);
    }
}
```

But that does not do the trick. Unfortunatly the detected file extension is not fix - thus I can not use a rule for a fix extension.

How can I configure the system to just respond with the content and without the Content-Disposition header (which leads to an f.txt download)? I would not like to use a slash ("/") at the end.

I already looked at the following ressource

- [Spring MVC controller browser downloads "f.txt"](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4220)
- [Add property support for configureContentNegotiation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4240)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Spring Framework 4.1.9 and 4.2.3 the Content-Disposition header was fixed to use the "inline" type which only suggests a file download name, should the content end up being downloaded. It won't force a Save As dialog any more.

Note also that the reason for the Content-Disposition header in the first place is to protect applications against RFD attacks. This is a very complex issue but you can see a summary in the [CVE-2015-5211](https://pivotal.io/security/cve-2015-5211) report.

Comment: Still `Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=f.txt` with Spring Framework 4.1.8 (when using Spring IO Platfrom 1.1.4) but definitely `Content-Disposition: inline;filename=f.txt` when using Spring IO Platform 2.0.0 (with Spring Framework 4.2.3). Upgrade is the solution for me. Thanks!

Comment: Yes indeed it's 4.1.9 (released today) and 4.2.3 that have the fix. I've updated that above.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues with Spring Boot as described [here](http://flnjworkingnotes.blogspot.com/2015/09/migrating-spring-rest-service.html).

What worked for me is the following configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);

    }


}
```

Comment: Today and for your (Franz') use case i'd propose that as well. A while back i had a similar problem: I wanted to use the file suffix (i.e. .jpg, .xml etc.) inside my controller method (i know that  the "right" way is to handle that via different views) and i solved it using my own path matcher: http://info.michael-simons.eu/2011/03/09/creating-a-better-pathmatcher-for-spring-3/ I guess that would work with Boot as well

Comment: Unfortunatly this does not work. It is not the problem that the request is not matched proberly to the Controller method but that the response always contains the `Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=f.txt` header wich leads the browser of offer a download instead of just showing the JSON result.

Comment: I even do not want to make my `CustomWebMvcConfigurerAdapter` a `@Configuration` class. Instead I would like to follow the advice as documented in the Spring Boot [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html): _If you want to keep Spring Boot MVC features, and you just want to add additional MVC configuration (interceptors, formatters, view controllers etc.) you can add your own @Bean of type WebMvcConfigurerAdapter, but without @EnableWebMvc._

Comment: Are you using `@RestController ` or `@Controller` annotation for your controller? If second, add '@ResponseBody' to your method annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set:

1) `Content-Disposition: inline;` -> you can use:

return new ResponseEntity(body, headers, statusCode); and set Content-Disposition in headers.
Look here:
[How to set 'Content-Disposition' and 'Filename' when using FileSystemResource to force a file download file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601428/how-to-set-content-disposition-and-filename-when-using-filesystemresource-to) 
and
[Return a stream with Spring MVC's ResponseEntity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333394/return-a-stream-with-spring-mvcs-responseentity)

2) `text/x-json` - Experimental MIME type for JSON before `application/json` got officially registered.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{fromLat}/{fromLon}/{toLat}/{toLon:.+}", method = {RequestMethod.GET},
                produces = {"text/x-json"})
```

It will try to display the content instead of downloading it.

Hope it will help.

Comment: I do not know how tow change the Content-Disposition to inline in a @RestController. If it works it would probably be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks. At the moment I would rather not change my @RequestMapping method to return the ResponseEntity object instead of my current _foobar_ object which is converted to JSON automatically. But if I will not find any other options I will probably give it a try.