# Spring4.2.2 @Pathvariable with dot(.) I want to return Json but return f.txt

Tags: java, json, spring

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/locate/latlng/{lat:.+},{lng:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")     
public ApiResultModel<LocateModel> getLocate(@PathVariable("lat") Double lat, @PathVariable("lng") Double lng)
```

Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=f.txt

Comment: Update/format above and ask clear questions.

Comment: eg:v1/locate/latlng/39.995668,116.480255

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34184392/5628401

Comment: Upgrade is the solution,with Spring Framework 4.2.3

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade is the solution,with Spring Framework 4.2.3

Comment: Still Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=f.txt with Spring Framework 4.1.8 (when using Spring IO Platfrom 1.1.4) but definitely Content-Disposition: inline;filename=f.txt when using Spring IO Platform 2.0.0 (with Spring Framework 4.2.3)