# Why I have this wrong behavior passing an e-mail address as value of a Spring MVC path variable?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, path-variables

I am finding some difficulties with this particular case of **path variable** use in Spring MVC.

So I open an URL like this:

```
localhost:8080/my-project/utenze/my.username/confermaEmail/my.email@google.com
```

Into my controller class I have this controller method that handle URL like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "utenze/{username}/confermaEmail/{email}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String confermaModificaEmail(@RequestHeader(value = HEADER_USER_CG) String codicefiscale, 
                                        @PathVariable String username, @PathVariable String email, Model model)  {

        logger.info("INTO confermaModificaEmail(), indirizzo e-mail: " + email);

        ...................................................................
        ...................................................................
        ...................................................................

        return "myView";
}
```

The previous request is correctly handled but I have the following problem with the **email** path variable value.

The problem is that the **email** path variable value is not **my.emai@google.com** as I expect but it is **my.emai@google**.

Spring is automatically deleting the last **.com** section of the inserted value.

Why? What is the problem? What am I missing? How can I try to solve this issue?

Comment: a quick way to fix this issue is : make a method (for example emailFixer) and check email(method parameter) with existence of .com at last of email and if it wasn't there then add it and return it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/34164388/2696260

Answer (score 2):

In your case I would remove the `{email}` from the path variable and request it via the request parameter:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "utenze/{username}/confermaEmail", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String confermaModificaEmail(@RequestHeader(value = HEADER_USER_CG) String codicefiscale, 
                                    @PathVariable String username, @RequestParam(value="email", required=true) String email, Model model)  {

    logger.info("INTO confermaModificaEmail(), indirizzo e-mail: " + email);

    ...................................................................
    ...................................................................
    ...................................................................

    return "myView";}
```

Have a try at this =)

Comment: This is not a solution for me because I have to use this URL that don't use parameter for email value

Comment: It will fail for `username` too, because user name contains dot too.

Comment: This method is recommended rather than sending it as a path-variable.