# Jasper Report using spring: file format and extension don't match xls

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets, jasper-reports

I have testing application on Spring mvc, for reporting using JasperReports, my code is this:

```
        response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "testExcel.xls");
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        ServletOutputStream outputStream=response.getOutputStream();
        ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();
          String filename = "/WEB-INF/resources/jasperReports/testExcel.jasper";
          Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<>();
          List<Customer>  listCustomer = service.listDataSource();
          JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(listCustomer);
            try {
                InputStream is = context.getResourceAsStream(filename);
                if (is != null) {
                    JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(is);
                    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, params, dataSource);
                    JRXlsExporter exporterXLSX = new JRXlsExporter();
                    exporterXLSX.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
                    exporterXLSX.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE);
                    exporterXLSX.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
                    exporterXLSX.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);
                    exporterXLSX.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, outputStream);
                    exporterXLSX.exportReport();
                    is.close();
                    outputStream.flush();
                    outputStream.close();
                }
            } catch (JRException exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
```

and reports generates but can not open because of error : file format and extension don't match testExcel.xls
what's wrong i don't get. dataSource  is good because i successfully generated pdf using it.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [HTTP response header content disposition for attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5278975/876298) & [How to set 'Content-Disposition' and 'Filename' when using FileSystemResource to force a file download file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16601428/876298)